# How to make an Emoji App? (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, emoji

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making An Emoji Enabeling App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225514/making-an-emoji-enabeling-app)

I'm wanting to be educated on how to create an emoji type app with the code. But i can't seem to find a tutorial for it. So I thought I would ask on here if anyone will help me. I've got Xcode and a $99 license too for testing it out on my device.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556647/create-custom-international-keyboard-for-iphone there is like a billion questions just like this on SO. You should just search.

Comment: "Make an emoji app"  Like what?  The iOS keyboard already supports a massive amount of emoji since iOS 5, with more support on the way in iOS 6.  There's no code necessary.

Comment: So why are there 3 emoji apps on the top 100 charts if no code is needed?

Comment: I just want to learn how its done. So you click a button and it says 'emoji enabled' or something. i wannna see the code for it

Comment: They're probably just Unicode apps.  They add a couple of chars into a text field, allow you to Email and text them off with the MF framework, and bam, instant success.  [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940278/why-cant-emoji-display-correctly-in-uitextfield)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emoji chars are simply Unicode chars, just with more limited support as you progress backwards through iOS history.  To enter emoji using the keyboard, iOS 5 and 6 provide the system standard Emoji keyboard (settings>general>international>keyboards>emoji).  In code, any standard text rendering object will show most escaped chars you pass to them:

```
UITextView *example = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
[example setText:@"\U0001F604"];
[self.view addSubview: example];
```

Simple as that.

Note that prior to iOS 5, text rendered and sent as Emojis utilizes the iOS private Unicode space, which means anybody not on an iOS device will get a whole lot of ? And [] instead of characters.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225514/making-an-emoji-enabeling-app) for the hack that enables the emoji keyboard in most of those emoji apps on the store.