# Why do I not get back my Last Name properly from Facebook iOS SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk

Well, I am from Spain and my Last Name is González (with á). I'm trying to get it from the Facebook SDK but what I get is Gonz√°lez instead of González.

Any suggestion?

Comment: sounds like encoding problem, but then again, i dont know much about iphone fb-sdk

Comment: If it is encoding problem then you can try my answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886903/iphone-how-to-write-symbol-on-a-label/9887028#9887028.

Comment: @SergioCalvoGonzález You can refer my link.

Comment: Yes but if I also have a NSString I can't do [NSString stringWithUTF8String:myString];

Comment: @SergioCalvoGonzález : Why ? Have you tried it ?

Comment: @Devang yes, and it says "Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'const char *' is disallowed with ARC"

Comment: In Your case you can try this `const char *my = [myString UTF8String];`

Comment: Ok, is there any way to cast a const char * to a NSString?

Comment: By the way, when I try your solution I have Gonz‚àö¬∞lez instead of González

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try following code :

```
- (NSString *) decodedString:(NSString *) originalString {
    NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[originalString cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
    return newString;
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem. And I am also going to add this code at : [iPhone how to write symbol on a label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886903/iphone-how-to-write-symbol-on-a-label/9887028#9887028) in my answer.